# What dice do I need to display every integer up to X?

Tags: code-golf

You may have seen something called a "perpetual dice calendar":
[image: perpetual dice calendar]

Two 6-sided dice can be rearranged and rotated. One die has the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. The second die has the numbers 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, and 8. With this, any day of the month—from 1 to 31—can be displayed on the front of the calendar. *The `6` can be rotated to be used as a `9`.*

However, what if I wanted to display any number up to... 100? 365? 50287? How many 6-sided dice would I need then, and what numbers would be printed on their sides?

The challenge:

- Given a whole number input X, output the fewest possible 6-sided dice that are required to display all integers from 1 up to and including X.
- Each side of a die must contain exactly one integer, from 0 to 8 inclusive.
- `6`'s may be used as `9`'s.
- If not every side of every die needs to have a number on it, then those side(s) must have `0`.
- Each line of the output should represent a die, e.g.:

```
Input: 4
Output:
0 0 1 2 3 4

Input: 6
Output:
1 2 3 4 5 6

Input: 9
Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 6 7 8

Input: 31
Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 6 7 8

Input: 35
Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 6 7
0 0 0 0 0 8
```

- The output lines can be in any format, e.g.:

```
123456
1 2 3 4 5 6
1,2,3,4,5,6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

- Assume that all the dice are used for every number, using leading 0's if necessary. For instance, if X is 35, then `2` would be displayed as `002`, because 3 dice are necessary.
- The outputted numbers do not need to be in any particular order.
- There may be multiple solutions for X. You need only output one.
- Standard golfing rules apply.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC, and nice first question!

Comment: I only now notice the "_Each line of the output should represent a die, with the numbers on the die delimited by spaces_" rule. Is this mandatory, or can we also just output as a list of lists of digits for example?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Lists are also accepted. I'll update my post.

Comment: I have a feeling this challenge is going to get a short Nekomata answer

Comment: What is the expected output for 6? I assume it is one normal six-sided die (i.e. no zero is required)? Probably worth adding to the examples either way.

Comment: What is the expected output for `88`? All the answers here that I can run output four dice, but it seems to me that it can be done in three, since you only need two of each of nine digits.

Comment: @Neil You'll need three 0's, as every dice needs to be used (with leading zeroes). eg. 001, 002, 003 ... will require a 0 on all 3 dice.

Comment: @MatthewJensen Oh, so you have to use all of the dice? I thought you just had to use two dice since the input had two digits. I didn't find that clear at all.

Comment: "6's may be used as 9's." - may 9s also be used as 6s?  In other words, is ```1 2 3 4 5 9``` a valid output for input ```6```?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It is not. For this challenge, 9's may not be in the output. :)

Comment: @Neil It's only mentioned in this bullet point "Assume that all the dice are used for every number..."

Comment: "If not every side of every die needs to have a number on it, then those side(s) must have 0." - Does this mean each die needs to minimise the numbers used? In other words, have the maximum number of 0's possible?

Comment: @MatthewJensen Yeah, I had to read that a few times to understand.

Comment: You say the output for 35 is three dice, with the third dice being used just for digit 8. But I think the two dice `0 1 2 3 4 5` and `1 2 3 6 7 8` are enough?

Comment: @Stef With just those two dice, you would not be able to form `05` or `04`.

Comment: What's the point of the "If not every side of every die needs to have a number on it, then those side(s) must have 0." rule?

Comment: @theonlygusti I was thinking in terms of a physical product you might use yourself - having sides that are blank is going to be less useful than sides with `0`'s. It's the most common number you'll need, so we want to make it as easy to find as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>29</s> 17 bytes

```
~≈∩h9F5?6=+ẇṅ6∆Z⁋
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJ+4omI4oipaDlGNT82PSvhuofhuYU24oiGWuKBiyIsIiIsIjU1NSJd)

*-12 bytes by taking some ideas from @Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer*

I believe this is correct but I'm not completely sure.

```
~≈                # keep only those numbers where all digits are equal from the implicit range [1, input]
  ∩               # transpose
   h              # first element
    9F            # remove nines 
      5?6=+       # 6 if input is 6 otherwise 5
           ẇ      # split into chunks of that length
            ṅ     # join
             6∆Z  # pad with zeros to length 6
                ⁋ # join by newlines
```

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines and I think it _almost_ works. I think it becomes suboptimal though. For example, I think we can do away with the last die [outputted for \$666666\$](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJmdjHhuYXijIrhuK044oi1P0zigLk4KivKgTgl4oC6NT82PSvhuofhuYU24oiGWuKBiyIsIiIsIjY2NjY2NiJd) by, instead, replacing one of the zeros on a die that does not currently contain a \$6\$ with a \$6\$. EDIT: but I could still be wrong about this!

Comment: Actually, I'm not so sure about that anymore since all lower six digit rep-digit numbers (\$111111\$, \$222222\$, \$333333\$, \$444444\$, \$555555\$) need all of the zeros to remain in place on the existing dice for \$666665\$ - starting to think this must be optimal :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan In order to produce all nine (or any seven) numbers less than ten, there needs to be a 0 on every die.

Comment: @Nitrodon yep, I realised that and used it in my explanation - once we get to seven we need a zero on the other dice, and thereafter we need at least one zero on all the dice so we can make all the rep-digits (including single digit ones).

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>22</s>  20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
D€EƇZḢḟ9s<7+5Ɗo0x6¤Y
```

A full program that accepts a positive integer and prints a set of dice as lines each having six digits from \$[0,8]\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/lUdMa12PtUQ93LHq4Y75lsY25tumxrnyDCrNDSyL/6xxuV8l61DDHiutRw1xNEIsLxPr/38jICAA)**

#### How?

For small inputs (\$\le 6\$) we should fill a single die with the numbers we need and then zeros.

For larger numbers, we:

- need multiple dice since one dice only has six sides, and
- only place up to five non-zero digits on the first dice (since we will need at least one leading zero to represent small numbers like \$7\$ or \$8\$)

When we reach a rep-digit that is not repeated nines (e.g. \$444\$) we need to ensure that enough of the dice have that digit (in this case three of them), and that any others contain a zero (since we will need them in front to represent the rep-digit).

Thus an optimal output for numbers greater than six is to set the first face of every die to \$0\$ and fill the remaining faces with the digits \$1\$ to \$8\$ in order as required by either the number itself (excluding \$9\$) or the digit of the rep-digit we have reached that we cannot yet make.

Thus for inputs greater than six we:

- fill the first dice with \$[1,2,3,4,5,0]\$
- fill the second dice with \$[6,7,a,b,c,0]\$ where \$a\$, \$b\$ and \$c\$ are \$0\$ until we encounter \$8\$ (a non-nines rep-digit), \$11\$ and \$22\$ whereupon they should be filled with \$8\$, \$1\$ and \$2\$ respectively.
- at \$33\$ create a new dice \$[3,d,e,f,g,0]\$ where \$d\$, \$e\$, \$f\$, and \$g\$ are \$0\$ until we encounter \$44\$, \$55\$, \$66\$, and \$77\$ whereupon they should be filled with \$4\$, \$5\$, \$6\$, and \$7\$ respectively.
- etc.

```
D€EƇZḢḟ9s<7+5Ɗo0x6¤Y - Main Link: positive integer, N
 €                   - for each i in [1,N]:
D                    -   decimal digits
   Ƈ                 - keep those for which:
  E                  -   all equal -> [[1],[2],...,[9],[1,1],[2,2],...,[9,9],...,[1,1,1],...]
    Z                - transpose
     Ḣ               - head -> [1,2,...,9,1,2,...,9,1,...]
      ḟ9             - filter out nines
             Ɗ       - last three links as a monad - f(N):
         <7          -   less than seven?
            5        -   five
           +         -   add -> 6 if N < 7 else 5
        s            - (filtered list of digits) split into chunks of length (that)
                          e.g.:  N=3 -> [[1,2,3]]
                                N=44 -> [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,1,2],[3,4]]
                  ¤  - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
               0     -   zero
                 6   -   six
                x    -   repeat -> [0,0,0,0,0,0]
              o      - logical OR (vectorises)
                          e.g.:  N=3 -> [[1,2,3,0,0,0]]
                                N=44 -> [[1,2,3,4,5,0],[6,7,8,1,2,0],[3,4,0,0,0,0]]
                   Y - join with newline characters
```

Comment: Excellent explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: If we're being a stickler for the rules, I'd mention that the lists of dice numbers need to be on separate lines, one per die.

Comment: @SpyderScript Thanks, great question too! I've edited it from a function that yields the list of dice to a full program that prints lines. I'd suggest keeping I/O as flexible as possible in future questions (I'm so used to this that I ignored that and just read it as a set of examples / tests).

Comment: Sorry for mistyping your name. (Normally I copy and paste it but because I was mentioning @AndrovT as well I didn't bother.)

Comment: Not a problem :)

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, <s>161 122 120</s> 122 bytes

*saved 39 bytes after looking at AndrovT's solution and fixing error for n=6*

*saved 2 more bytes after realizing the die for N=6 didn't need to have a 1*

*added 2 bytes because the previous statement was false*

```
=LET(x,ROW(1:8),y,LEN(A1),z,A1=6,IFERROR(HSTACK(z*1,MOD(SEQUENCE(INT((y*8+MAX(x*(REPT(x,y)*1<=A1))-4-z)/5),5)+z-1,8)+1),))
```

The formula above determines how many faces are needed to cover all numbers less than or equal to N then generates dice from the list below so there at least that many faces.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 6 7 8 1 2
0 3 4 5 6 7
0 8 1 2 3 4
0 5 6 7 8 1
0 2 3 4 5 6
0 7 8 1 2 3
0 4 5 6 7 8
```

If N = 6 it uses `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

**Explanation:**

```
=LET(x,ROW(1:8),           # x = array 1..8
y,LEN(A1),                 # y = number of digits in N 
z,A1=6,                    # z = (N=6)
IFERROR(~,)                # Pads errors with 0
HSTACK(z*1,~)                # Concatenates 0 to other 5 faces
MOD(SEQUENCE(~,5)+z-1,8)+1 # array of last 5 faces for each die
INT((~)/5)                 # number of dice needed
y*8+MAX(x*(~))-4-z         # 4 + number of faces needed to cover all numbers up to ~
REPT(x,y)*1<=A1            # calculates the largest number the same length as N with repeated digits
```

Comment: "_saved 2 more bytes after realizing the die for N=6 didn't need to have a 1_" Then how does it make `1` for \$n=6\$?.. For \$n=6\$ the output needs to be a single die with `1,2,3,4,5,6`, doesn't it?

Comment: You're right.  That's what I get for trying to think too late at night.

Answer (score 5):

## Python3, 475 bytes:

```py
from itertools import*
R=range
N=lambda k:k+[6,9]*(6 in k or 9 in k)
P=permutations
def f(n):
 q=[({*R(1,n+1)},[[]]if n<7 else[[0]])]
 while q:
  a,b=q.pop()
  if not a:return[[0]*(6-len(i))+i for i in b]
  t=str(min(a))
  for i in P(b,min(len(b),len(t))):
   for j,k in zip_longest(t,i):
    j=int(j)
    if not k or j not in N(k):
     D=[*b,[0,j]]if len(b[-1])==6 else[*b[:-1],b[-1]+[j]];q+=[(a-{int(''.join(map(str,K)))for d in P(D,len(D))for K in product(*map(N,d))},D)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVDLbsMgEDzXX7G3gE2iRGndxi233CJFUa4IVbjGDX4AwURVG/XbU7CrHBDs7Aw7s/bbn4xev1h3u9XO9KC8dN6YbgDVW@N8mhypE/pTJnvaib6sBLRFm7GcbHiKclAaWjAONuMLJwdqpesvXnhl9JBUsoYaaVwkcKYMXdMjWhGdrfAvYYxzVYN@ewbZDZKxJeeYJ/B1Up2Ec1CAICU9L6yxCIcqko0HUTjpL05HQXAw76RGCuNMQR18qOijDN@Ap4N3qFcaCRzl9@4BlSTCUVhiEi@PcbQ4kRrSRtqPsu@dCckHjzxRUx8aqrRHDR6Lf0fjAprxGXR71P5zYUtZWhK2JM0YdRzI5iuOKc2n0GnJigCQEc5Y4L2es7AoMb/GObPZojHBai8sCmnILviMFqspx3Y0v52wXcSsM9Xlw6M0KvakwmHRW8xv9/DskUBOYENgvQrniRfJg3VxVh23ePsD)

Comment: shouldn't the first 2 test cases have a `1`?

Comment: @c-- Yes indeed, thank you for catching. Saved a few bytes in the process :)

Comment: [455 bytes](https://tio.run/##PVDLTsMwEDyTr9gbdmKqVkCgAd96q1RxtyzkEIc6D9t1XCGo@PayTlEPlr2zM57Z9d9x7@z9sw/ncxvcCCbqEJ0bJjCjdyHm2Y4PaqwbBX3VF6Jka5mT0ljowQVYpwfN3rjXYTxGFY2zU9boFlpiaZXBgQtyyoOyn5qsmC1W9JcJsZTCvj5VUlKZwdfeDBoOSAbFan5YeOcJxcq0YF0EVQUdj8EKYgpU5iUVVSlbdDeA9jV@AZFPMZDRWKJokl67b6RmCR60JTVl6YqUpmQXUsf6RPsx/n1wGHKKJDJz6UPHjY2ko3Pxn2Yeu5ufqNuR/p8LGy7ymokl66RE7mwo7laScl7qYdLYFRXWbEYLgbSXQ4HrUXenZHN7u@gcJh2VJzgM22LMlLC5jLGZs28u2DZhPrjm@BFJnhQ71lBc7YbK83V28cCgZLBmcL/C8yir7MaH5NUSQ@n5Dw), t feels like `(6in k or 9in k)` can be golfed but I didn't see how, maybe something in the tips?

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES8), 111 bytes

Algorithm shamelessly borrowed from [@AndrovT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260444/58563)'s latest version, which itself uses ideas from [@JonathanAllan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260448/58563).

Returns an array of digit strings.

```javascript
n=>n-6?(g=n=>n?g(n-1)+(/^([1-8])\1*$/.test(n)?n%10:''):'')(n).match(/.{1,5}/g).map(s=>s.padEnd(6,0)):["123456"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzLCsIwFET3fkUQxRtNU6O2@CDtyo0LXbisFUIfsaI3pQmCiN9eWwcOzJnF3NVL2aypauehyYu2lC3KCL0wBi37FmtAT9AZ@FdIhLdO6UVMRz53hXWANMaxmG8nE9rTOX8ql93A5x/Bgq@v@6EGKyPLa5XvMYeQzSndJkOxWK6CcJi2u2TFSMjIhpGl6AjSAS9Ns1fdDxIZkcygNY@CP4yGw/l05NY1FeqqfEMJyJ05/x1on/YH)

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
Ｅ⪪⁻⭆ΦＩ…·¹Ｎ⁼⌊ι⌈ι⌊ι9⁺⁵⁼θ6⭆◨ι⁶Σλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCsIwEEWvUrKaQgVdWCoui0IXlWK9QAyhHUjStEmKnj5Oiuhm@PPmzRcjX8TEVYzdgsZDyy30ViElNMFB7wkPiV5ReblAzZ2HxggVHK7yzs0g4VBkjbHB34J@kpLneZFd5sCVSy2ogwYk1PLXNyfhf6GFnRjNjkrh@PudiZdsk@u3ULIeJwubg0X2QC03me1ZMkryzjFWVdyt6gM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Once I'd figured out what the problem actually was, this is an implementation of @Axuary's observation, although comparing the other answers I see I ended up with the same basic algorithm as @AndrovT and @JonathanAllan but only by coincidence.

```
      …·                        Inclusive range from
        ¹                       Literal integer `1` to
         Ｎ                      First input as a number
     Ｉ                          Vectorised cast to string
    Φ                           Filtered where
           ⌊ι                   Minimum digit
          ⁼                     Is equal to
             ⌈ι                 Maximum digit
   ⭆           ⌊ι               Extract one digit from each repdigit
  ⁻              9              Remove `9`s
 ⪪                              Split into groups of
                   ⁵            Literal integer `5`
                  ⁺             Plus
                     θ          First input
                    ⁼           Equals
                      6         Literal string `6`
Ｅ                              Map over groups
                        ◨ι⁶     Pad to 6 characters
                       ⭆   Σλ   Replace spaces with `0`s
                                Implicitly print
```

The above code is sublinear in `X`, so here's more efficient 35-byte version:

```
Ｅ⪪⁻⭆⁺÷×⁹⊕ＮＸχＬθ×⁹⊖Ｌθ﹪⊕ι⁹0⁺⁵⁼θ6⭆◨ι⁶Σλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NDoIwEIRfpeG0JDXBgwTiFQ8kYoj4AhUa2KQ/UFp8/NpyUG673@zMTj8x02smvG8NKgsNm6GbBYYJlVuhswGPkbYirLWyFW44cHih5CuUlNSqN1xyZfkQ5NnZh5NvbiBNU0pa/QnjOaPkztVoJ1h2/DNX/G8@XISTRg9OaDimY8Bl1JIsidmx0IWS2@KYWGEJPE9276E0G544ThaQkjwqToKID67eF4U/beIL) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Calculates the number of repdigits up to `X` as equal to the first digit of `(X+1)*9` plus `9` times the length of `X` as a string plus a correction factor, then takes the sequence modulo `9` omitting the zeros and wraps into rows as above.

The problem would have been much more interesting if each number only needed to be formed from `1+floor(log10(X))` dice. In that case, my best patterns so far are as follows:

- 6: 123456
- 9: 123456, 78
- 10: 012345, 0678
- 21: 012345, 06781
- 32: 123450, 678012
- 54: 123456, 781234, 0
- 65: 123456, 781234, 05
- 76: 123456, 781234, 056
- 87: 123456, 781234, 0567
- 99: 123456, 781234, 05678
- 221: 123456, 781234, 056781, 0
- 332: 123456, 781234, 056781, 02
- 443: 123456, 781234, 056781, 023
- 554: 123456, 781234, 056781, 0234
- 665: 123456, 781234, 056781, 02345
- 776: 123456, 781234, 056781, 023456
- 887: 123456, 781234, 056781, 023456, 7
- 999: 123456, 781234, 056781, 023456, 78
- 1110: 123456, 781234, 056781, 023456, 780
- 2221: 123456, 781234, 056781, 023456, 7801
- 3332: 123456, 781234, 056781, 023456, 78012
- 4443: 123456, 781234, 056781, 023456, 780123

I believe that the dice will then continue cyclically though the digits after that point.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 44 (or 42†) [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[8Ý6ãNã.ΔULε§Xgj„9 60‡œεXsøε`å}P}à}P}D¸àd#}»
```

Extremely slow brute-force, so it'll time out for \$n\geq7\$ on TIO..
Not too happy with how long `` §Igj„9 60‡œεXsøε`å}P}à `` is. Will see if I can find something shorter (and hopefully faster) later on.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AUoAtf9vc2FiaWX//1s4w502w6NOw6MuzpRVTM61wqdYZ2rigJ45IDYw4oChxZPOtVhzw7jOtWDDpX1QfcOgfVB9RMK4w6BkI33Cu///NA) or [verify some of the smaller test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W96bJKSZ15BaYmVgpK936GVOlxK/qUlEL7O/2iLw3PNDi/2O7xY79yU0EPrDs89t/XQ8oj0rEcN8ywVzAweNSw8Ovnc1ojiwzvObU04vLQ2oPbwAiDhcmjH4QUpyrWHdv/XObTN/j8A).

† With looser output-format of a list of lists of digits, the trailing `}»` can be removed for -2 bytes.

**Explanation:**

```python
[               # Start an infinite loop:
 8Ý             #  Push a list in the range [0,8]
   6ã           #  Cartesian power of 6 to create all sextets using these digits
     Nã         #  Cartesian power with the 0-based loop-index
 .Δ             #  Find the first one that's truthy for,
                #  or -1 if none are truthy:
   U            #   Pop and store the current list in variable `X`
   Ý            #   Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input-integer]
    ε           #   Map over each value:
      Xg        #    Push the length of list `X`
     §  j       #    Pad leading spaces to make the current integer that length
         „9 60‡ #    Transliterate 9s to 6s and spaces to 0s
     œ          #    Get all permutations of this integer
      ε         #    Map over each permutation:
       Xs       #     Push list of lists `X` and swap
         ø      #     Create pairs of the two lists
          ε     #     Map over each pair of [list,digit]
           `    #      Pop and push the list and digit separately to the stack
            å   #      Check if the digit is in the list
          }P    #     After the map: check whether it's truthy for all [list,digit]-pairs
      }à        #    After the map: check whether it's truthy for any permutation
    }P          #   After the map: check whether it's truthy for all values in the range
  }D            #  After the find_first: Duplicate the resulting -1 or list
    ¸           #  Wrap it into a list
     à          #  Pop and push the flattened maximum
      d         #  If this maximum is non-negative (thus not -1):
       #        #   Stop the infinite loop
}»              # After the infinite loop: join each inner list of the valid find_first
                # by spaces, and then all strings by newlines
                # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 18 bytes (36 nibbles)

```
&"0"6`/ ?-$6 5 $ |+|.,$`$`@~$~<<$- 9
```

Same approach as [Androv T's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260444/95126): upvote that one!

```
|+|.,$`$`@~$~<<$- 9 # part 1: get the nonzero digits needed:
   .                # map over
    ,               # range from 1..
     $              # input
        `@ $        #   convert to digits in base           
          ~         #   10
      `$            #   and remove duplicates
  |                 # now filter to keep only
            ~       # falsy elements when
             <<$    #   dropping the first element of each list
 +                  # flatten the list of (1-element) lists
|                   # and filter again to keep only
                    # elements that are truthy (positive) when
                - 9 #   subtracted from 9
&"0"6`/ ?-$6 5 $    # part 2: split them into dice:
     `/             # split into chunks of
        ?           #   if
         -$6        #     input minus 6 is truthy
             5      #   then 5
               $    #   else input
&                   # now justify each chunk
    6               # to a width of 6
 "0"                # using "0" as a filler
```

[image]

---

Frustratingly, if we were allowed to use `9`s instead of `6`s (rather than `6`s instead of `9`s), which would correspond to identical physical dice, we could have:

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 16.5 bytes (33 nibbles; but not permitted output)

```
&"0";6`/ +`$- $@ $ +`%+|.,@`$`@~$~<<
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 120 bytes

```python
n=input()
m=n>6
for v in zip(*[(i%10for i in range(n>1,n+1)+4*[0]if len(set(`i`))<2-i%10/9)]*(6-m)):print'0'*m+`v`[1::3]
```

A full program that accepts a positive integer from STDIN and prints the dice.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcvRCoIwFADQd79iL@G9W5KzEBvpj4zBetC60K5jLaF@fuHrgRO/@blyVwqPxPGTAasw8tRXy5rEJojFjyJIC3TQ7W60W7rzYwae9JGVRnWRtnW0iNfM8J4zePKIt67Zz@mKTkLfBEQTE3Gu21oG5TdvtTFnV8ow/AE)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##RVDRasMwDHz3V@hl2E6cLU7arDVzfyQLJG3dzlArIfXK1rJvz2wzmEDoOKS7Q9O3/xixWg7j0WhK6fuC2uL06RknTuOuIadxhhtYhLudWNYy@yTLyNnIzQOeDcOdFJhLnq@ytuzsCS4G2dV41tue87eqiDcvW95lrCkc52qaLXpa0szl/a1vpVJ1twT3VhWyIyQF0JfB7Y@D8ubqU4gIoieTAioBtYCVgEbANuBA1WsBm9fQGwEyVvk3JVcEQiVToEkcNDx@FH0Oum7wLErztGS@zAHiM/5Pll8).

This employs the same method I used in [my Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260448/53748).